# What's the max size and weight allowed for an international flight checked baggage with LOT Polish Airlines?

Tags: international-travel, warsaw, lot-polish-airlines

I will be flying with LOT Polish Airlines for an international trip and was wondering what is the maximum size and weight allowed for an economy standard passenger's checked baggage?